# How to open Xcode 5 Autosizing Window

Tags: ios, xcode, layout

My Xcode 5 has this window, no autosizing button!

[image]

How to open layout like this one!

[image]

Comment: Just a wild guess, but is auto layout on in your project? If so turn it off then you can see it.